# Why does my variable matches the wrong if() condition?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I have

```
echo $role;

if  (!$role=='trial_expired') { echo 'not expired '; } else { echo 'expired '; }
```

$Role outputs 'trial' which is the correct userrole according to the database, but the followed condition still returns false, returning 'expired'. For some reason, 'trial' (my guess because it it partial of 'trial_expired') is treated the same as trial_expired. With what operators can I fix the condition?

Comment: A word of warning, [`==` in PHP is just silly](http://3v4l.org/ulqj3). Make a habit of using `===`, `strcmp`, and other strict operators instead.

Comment: `!$role` evaluates first, becoming `false`, which then gets compared to `'trial_expired'`. a non-empty string evalutes to a boolean true, so you're going `true == false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're putting your `!` logic operator in the wrong spot. To compare if strings are **not** equal, you need to have the `!` operator placed immediately to the left of your equality comparators (`==`).

```
if ($role!=='trial_expired') { echo 'not expired '; } else { echo 'expired '; }
```

Comment: It should be `!=`, not `!==`.

Comment: @thecoder16 Why not `!==`?

Comment: @thecoder16 `!==` [is valid](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It compares both type and equality, and it seems as though that's what the OP was attempting to do, just with the negation in the wrong spot.

Comment: Well, thats kind of embarrassing. Still, you saved me a lot of debugging, for some reason I kept overseeing that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, someone else used `!=` and from my python and java experience i thought that would be correct. I don’t code in php at all…

Answer (score 1):

Call me nuts but `trial` is not the same thing as `trial_expired`. PHP clearly agrees with me

Answer (score 1):

This condition makes no sense:

```
if  (!$role=='trial_expired') {echo 'not expired '; } else { echo 'expired '; }
```

If you want to check of a value is not equal, you do it with `!=` like this:

```
if  ($role != 'trial_expired') {echo 'not expired '; } else { echo 'expired '; }
```

Also, you should format conditions like that this way:

```
if  ($role != 'trial_expired') {
  echo 'not expired ';
}
else {
  echo 'expired ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And *why* does this happen? The expression

```
!$role=='trial_expired'
```

is parsed as the following, which should look obviously incorrect.

```
(!$role) == 'trial_expired'
```

Either make the change suggested elsewhere, or use parenthesis to negate the desired expression.

```
!($role == 'trial_expired')
```